# How to store facebook token in AsyncStorage React Native(Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

**I am using Expo to Login User with Facebook, I am receiving token with Graph Api but when I try to add the token in Async Storage it is not working.**

Please see the code below:

```
async logIn() {
 try {
  const {
   type,
   token,
  } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('<APP_ID>', {
  permissions: ['public_profile'],
 });

 if (type === 'success') {
  // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
   fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((tokenKey) => AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken',tokenKey))
  .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('App'))
  } else {
    // type === 'cancel'
   }
 } catch ({ message }) {
  alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
 }
}
```

I am receiving the **token** when I **console** it

```
 fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((tokenKey) => console.log('userToken',tokenKey))
  .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('App'))
```

Please help, I am new to react native and asynchronous programming in JavaScript. **TIA** :)

Comment: What is the error you got ?

Comment: @RoshanGautam I am getting no error but when I set token to Async storage navigate in .then is not working on the other hand when I console the token in(second code in question) it navigates to other screen. I also checked userToken in async storage but it is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry folks the problem was from my side, I was trying to store an object directly into **Async Storage**, whereas Async Storage only accepts values in **String** format. I used

```
.then((tokenKey) => AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken',JSON.stringify(tokenKey)))
```

and it fixed the problem,Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you want to get item from AsyncStorage

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken', (error, result) => {
    if (result) {
      //result
    }
    else {
      //error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting token from AsyncStorage with getItem?

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken').then((token) => {
            this.setState({hasToken: token !== null,localToken : token})
        });
```

Comment: Yes @cipli onat when I consoled the token in Async Storage it is **null**